error: Sandbox: rsync.samba in Xcode project
when integrating Realm into the Xcode project, two errors appear:

error: Sandbox: rsync.samba(23748) deny(1) file-write-create /Users/danilkoksenev/DerivedXcode/MyPlaces-egyurzcpvwpcvjbgtnifjfqlhsia/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/XCFrameworkIntermediates/Realm/Headers (in target 'Realm' from project 'Pods')

error: Sandbox: rsync.samba(23749) deny(1) file-write-create /Users/danilkoksenev/DerivedXcode/MyPlaces-egyurzcpvwpcvjbgtnifjfqlhsia/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/XCFrameworkIntermediates/Realm/.librealm-monorepo.a.iHlLDE (in target 'Realm' from project 'Pods')


First, Clean Build Folder, then I thought that this directory did not have enough rights or the SIP system on macOS was blocking it, I decided to move DerivedData to a user directory, namely to (/Users/danilkoksenev/DerivedXcode) and Clean Build Folder, which has all the necessary rights, but this did not help solve this error.
Also in the file .xcworkspace in the MyPlaces project changed the User Script Sandboxing Yes to No, it didn't help either
I also tried to change source="$(readlink "${source}")" to source="$(readlink -f "${source}")" in the Pods -> Pods-MyPlaces -> folder of the left area of Xcode, but this also did not solve this problem
My Podfile:
Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'
target 'MyPlaces' do
Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
use_frameworks!
Pods for MyPlaces
pod 'RealmSwift', '~>10'
end
Can you tell me what I should do to solve this error?

Welcome to SO. A number of things can be causing this error including outdated CocoaPods or even the Podfile contents. Please include your XCode version, CocoaPods version and your podfile in the question so we can see your environment. Secondly, Realm works out of the box with either CocoaPods or SPM and default XCode settings and we build projects with it all the time. That means it could also be an environment issue - I would advise not moving target files around until this issue is resolved. Please update the question with more details and we'll take a look. Are you building for Watch?

Xcode version: 15.3
CocoaPods version: cocoapods-1.15.2
Answering your question, am I a developer for Watch, no. I am a novice developer and have not yet decided what I will develop for, most likely for macOS and iOS.
I specified my podfile in the question (link) @Jay

Please include code, errors and structures as text, not links and images. That way, if they are needed in an answer, they can be copied and pasted. Also, if the links break, it would invalidate the question. Images are not searchable which may prevent future readers from locating the question.Take a look at No Images Please

Please specify your platform in the podfile. See Realm Install with CocoaPods. Then quit the project and from the project directory delete the podfile.lock file, then command line pod repo update and then  pod deintegrate and then sudo gem install cocoapods.

My podfile in the question: @Jay

I would like to clarify, do I need to register 'pod repo update' and other commands in the directory of my project or just in the home directory? @Jay

pod repo update is instructing Cocoapods to update all the repos and is not project specific. So it can be run anywhere. The install and deintegrate are project specific and should be run from the project directory.

Also, what's in the question as "My Podfile" isn't actually your podfile. In general, copy and paste the exact code, ensuring it's formatted for readability using the editor tools {}. Be sure to review the Realm Cocoapods install and note your podfile shows platform :ios, '9.0' which isn't compatible.

This error is related to User Script Sandboxing.
The easiest fix is to select your project in the navigator, then

select your target.

Go to Build Settings and in the search box enter sandbox

Then set all options to NO.


Here's a screen shot

Then, you'll need to go to Signing and Capabilities and check the boxes to allow incoming and outgoing network connections.

Oh - and don't forget with 10.50.0 for now, the framework needs to be embedded and signed.


In the settings of which file(.xcworkspace or .xcodeproj) should I change user script sandboxing to no? @Jay

@Danil When using CocoaPods, you should only open your project with the .xcworkspace file - that loads the complete project. Do not open just the .xcodeproj file. Those files are part of the same project so you can't change it in one and not the other because it's a project setting, not a file setting. So, once you've opened the project with the .xcworkspace file, then on the far left in the navigator, select the project name then your target file as shown in the screen shot and proceed from there. I just tested it again and those steps correct the issue described.

When I executed these commands in the terminal: pod repo update, pod deintegrate, sudo gem install cocoapods, logged in.xcworkspace in my navigator: Pods is lit red and all files related to realm and pods have been deleted @Jay

@Danil Great! Your project is cleaned up and reset. Now install the podfile as usual pod install. I would suggest removing the Podfile.lock before doing that as it's not needed at this point and will be re-created. Also see my latest comment to the question as you will need to update your podfile as well.

@Danil The App Sandbox is there by default. I would suggest adding it. As a test, you may want to try creating a brand new, fresh project and set it up per the install guide on the Realm Getting Started guide. That way you can see what the defaults are. I have set up numerous projects (almost daily) using that guide and as long as the steps are followed, it works 100% of the time.

Yes, I tried to add an App Sandbox, but I simply don't have it in capability @Jay

@Danil As you can see, SO is a terrible interactive debugger as we cannot see what you're seeing or what steps (were) taken. When selecting your target in Targets, and then Signing and Capabilities, theres a + Capability just to the left  of All. That presents a list of capabilities where you can type Sandbox and add it. If it's not there, it sounds like you have a corrupted/modified project or something that's preventing standard, default options. As suggested, try making a new project as a test so you can work through that process and see what the defaults are.

I would also like to ask you what if in .xcworkspace in the project navigator in the Frameworks folder: Pods_MyProject is lit red? And in the settings I also set  embed and sign @Jay

@Danil It will be lit red if the project is not opened with the correct file. All projects, when CocoaPods is installed, will have the standard Project_Name.xcodeproj file and then a newly added Project_Name.xcworkspace file. It's critical from then forward that the project only be opened with the Project_Name.xcworkspace file.

It worked for me. Thanks
